# Not able to run puppeteer-full page screenshot npm package

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, screenshot

I am using pupeeter package which is mentioned here
https://www.npmjs.com/package/puppeteer-full-page-screenshot

Code Script

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import fullPageScreenshot from 'puppeteer-full-page-screenshot';

(async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
   await page.goto('http://lambdatest.com/');

   await fullPageScreenshot(page, { path: './page.png' });

   await browser.close();
})();
```

But after running the script, I am getting following error

```
(node:39184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: fullPageScreenshot is not a function
    at file:///Users/arushsaxena/Desktop/DotlapseDemo/smartui-node-sample/puppeteer-lib.js:10:10
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:39184) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:39184) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call the `default()` function of `fullPageScreenshot` to make it work:

```
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';
import fullPageScreenshot from 'puppeteer-full-page-screenshot';

(async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
   await page.goto('http://lambdatest.com/');

   await fullPageScreenshot.default(page, { path: './page.png' });

   await browser.close();
})();
```

Alternatively, you can use `require` instead of `import` and assign the `default()` function to `fullPageScreenshot`:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fullPageScreenshot = require('puppeteer-full-page-screenshot').default;

(async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
   const page = await browser.newPage();
   await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });
   await page.goto('http://lambdatest.com/');

   await fullPageScreenshot(page, { path: './page.png' });

   await browser.close();
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
import puppeteer from 'puppeteer';

import fullPageScreenshot from 'puppeteer-full-page-screenshot';

(async () => {
   const browser = await puppeteer.launch();

   const page = await browser.newPage();

   await page.setViewport({ width: 1920, height: 1080 });

   await page.goto('http://lambdatest.com/');


   await page.screenshot({ path: 'fullpage.png', fullPage: true });

   await browser.close();
})();
```

Comment: where are you using full page screenshot. it is simple puppeteer function that you have used.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: you can see I passed fullPage option in the second last line.

Comment: This is not really an answer because it does not address the question at all, which is specifically about puppeteer-full-page-screenshot. The code in this answer makes no sense, fullPageScreenshot is not even used, even though it is imported, and standard screenshot() function which is used in the code is not a replacement for fullPageScreenshot().